# Configure ingres for frontend application not working

Tags: kubernetes

I try to set up ingres in order to view my frontend.

Everything looks OK, including using curl to verify it:

```
$ curl http://octopus.ea.mot-solutions.com
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://octopus.ea.mot-solutions.com/clustercontrol/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at octopus.ea.mot-solutions.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

However using the same http://octopus.ea.mot-solutions.com/ from my browser gives "This site can’t be reached"

Here are the details:
Running minikube on Linux Debian
describe service:

```
Name:                     fe-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=octopus-frontend
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.104.191.56
IPs:                      10.104.191.56
Port:                     <unset>  90/TCP
TargetPort:               9090/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31977/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.3:9090
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Describe ingres:

```
Name:             frontend-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.49.2
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host                          Path  Backends
  ----                          ----  --------
  octopus.ea.mot-solutions.com
                                /   fe-service:9090 (172.17.0.3:9090)
Annotations:                    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    25m (x2 over 26m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

I have used:

```
 kubectl expose deployment octopus-frontend --type=NodePort
```

and:

```
minikube service fe-service
```

and put the minikube ip to /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.49.2 octopus.ea.mot-solutions.com
```

minikube version: v1.25.2

Am I missing something?

Comment: could you try using the IP 192.168.49.2 in your browser? to narrow down it is not the DNS issue

Answer (score 1):

The node port number is missing in the url

```
http://octopus.ea.mot-solutions.com:31977
```

Comment: Thanks, but reading more about this I think I need to configure a proxy server to serve as an end point. Need to read some more about this I guess.